# How to reduce these 3 regular expressions into one only?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression (really 3 regular expressions) to separate bible verse references into:  Book, Chapter, Verse

For input I would have references such as

John 1:4
John 10:11
1 Peter 1:2-3
1 John 1:10
Acts 10:1-2
Song of Solomon 2:10

These would need to be separated into
--------------------------------------
Book            -  Chapter  -  Verse
--------------------------------------
John            -  1        -  4
John            -  10       -  11
1 Peter         -  1        -  2-3
1 John          -  1        -  10
Acts            -  10       -  1-2
Song of Solomon -  2        - 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(.+)\s+(\d+):(.+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bAi1FK/1)

Comment: That is almost too good of an answer.  I was really look for 3 expressions, one for each catagory

Comment: Try those three regexes: `^(.+)\s+`, `(\d+):`, `[^:]+$`

Comment: Just do `preg_match("/pattern/", $string, $foundMatches); print_r($foundMatches);'. You don't need 3 regexes